# Can't find msi file generated by Setup library project (wix)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm following a Wix tutorial that recommends creating a setup library project and writing this in Product.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="*" Name="HelloWix" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0" Manufacturer="SoftAgility" UpgradeCode="2CA1BA0A-99C0-445C-8C72-083431F757DE">

    <Package Description="Simple Demo" Compressed="yes" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="HelloWix" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Component Id="TextFileComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <File Source="C:\temp\MyFile.txt" />
    </Component>

    <Feature Id="MainFeature" Title="HelloWix" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="TextFileComponent" />
    </Feature>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

This project is meant to setup a simple hello world type of setup in order to show the simplest piece of code needed to get a working installation package, with minimal requirements. Build is successful. Question is: where is the .msi generated?

Answer (score 0):

Well, solution is I unloaded the wixproj and changed this line:
`<OutputType>Library</OutputType>`
to
`<OutputType>Package</OutputType>`
If you know of other methods, please add them. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the project templates provided by WiX? This [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_templates.html) explains the different project types.